# What is the difference between Bootstrap img-responsive and thumbnail classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used both in two different projects, but i can't seem to see the difference between the two. img-responsive seems a but messier, but i still don't know what they do exactly and how they differ?

[Project 1](http://codepen.io/Lilaa8/pen/qrmoPP): `class="thumbnail"`
[Project 2](http://codepen.io/Lilaa8/pen/ggNpaJ): `class="img-responsive"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Bootstrap source code:

```
.img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The .img-responsive class applies max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block to the image which effectively makes it scale to the width of its parent container.

The .img-thumbnail class applies styling to an image including padding and border